# Slick skip Evolution when using existing mysql table

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I have an existing MySQL DB. Now I've created a Slick model to query said DB.

My problem now is: when I try to connect the model to an existing table it doesn't work. It says it needs evolution.
But when I rename the table in Slick and make the evolution it creates a new Table that looks the same to me.

So my question is: why can't I use the existing table if it looks the same?

Is there a way to skip the evolution and try my luck?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say why you are having that behaviour without more details, but to disable `evolutions` go to `conf/application.conf`and you will find:

```
# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed 
# evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Uncomment and then evolutions will be disabled

Comment: exactly wht I neede. Thanks!